# Params always nil in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to just get an input and send it to controller.
 But the params in controller is always nil

View (index.html.erb)

```
   <%= form_tag(:controller => "zip_code_lookup", :action => 'index') do  %>
     <%= text_field_tag :zip_code, params[:zip_code] %>
     <%= submit_tag("go") %>
 <% end %>
```

Controller

```
 class ZipCodeLookupController < ApplicationController
    def index
         render :text => params[:zip_code].inspect
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `params[:zip_code]` in your controller, but **NOT** in your view.

In your `index.html.erb` view, replace:

```
<%= text_field_tag :zip_code, params[:zip_code] %>
```

with:

```
<%= text_field_tag :zip_code %>
```

Then, grab the `zip_code` value using `params[:zip_code]` in your controller action.

So, your view (`index.html.erb)`) becomes:

```
   <%= form_tag(:controller => "zip_code_lookup", :action => 'index') do  %>
     <%= text_field_tag :zip_code %>
     <%= submit_tag("go") %>
  <% end %>
```

See [this article](http://www.saalonmuyo.com/2010/01/27/using-form_tag-in-ruby-on-rails/) for some more information on how `form_tag` works.

Comment: Thank you again, I follow (
railscasts.com  #290 SOAP with Savon) but since it is old tutorial, I have faced problems.